# How do I research something at the library?

Tags: state-of-decay

To construct certain items, I have to research something at a library.

[image]

Earlier in the game Lily was discussing creating a library in the church so we had one on site but I've had a look around the church and was unable to find it.

Is the library a separate building or is it something I have to build before I can use it? How do I research something at the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes. The [Library](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Library) is a facility and you need to build it to research stuff.

- To research, just click on the Library and choose a project to research.
- Some projects require you have a specific facility first (for
  example to research Greenhouse Gardening you need a [Garden Area](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Garden_Area)
  first).
- Also, having someone with [Research](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Research) skill speeds up
  research time significantly.